# How to make a subdomain ajax call with jQuery (without iFrames)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, subdomain

**site.com/api/index.php** is where I need the ajax request to go. From **site.com/sub/** the request works perfectly but **sub.site.com** is sending the request to **sub.site.com/api/index.php** which obviously does not exist... I've Google and StackOverflowed the hell out of the question, but can't seem to find an answer that works.

Code:

```
var jQuery_ajax = {
   url: "site.com/api/index.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: $.param(urlData),
   dataType: "json"
}


var request = $.ajax(jQuery_ajax);
```

The most common answer was to set *document.domain* to the regular site, but that does not seem to do anything... I've also seen answers talking about iFrames, but I want to stay away from iFrames at all costs.

```
document.domain = "site.com";
```

** Note: everything is on the same server.

**HACKY SOLUTION:** made sub.site.com/api/index.php a file that simply reads

```
include_once("$path2site/api/index.php");
```

Comment: jsonp would be the easiest solution, followed by CORS and then followed by server-side proxy. don't forget the http:// part.

Comment: I think the call is hitting the wrong url because you have `site.com/api/index.php` instead of `http://site.com/api/index.php`. Once you fix that, you'll have to deal with the cross domain issues.

Comment: I've tried with the Http:// and you are correct -- I get an "is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've corrected the URL to `http://site.com/api/index.php` try adding the following to `api/index.php`:

`header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://sub.site.com");`

e: it's possible that doing so may disallow use from site.com as well; I'm not seeing a way to provide two values, so you may need a way to tell it which site to use, like a ?sub=1 arg to index.php

Comment: Just tried it. Doesn't work.. still get "POST http://sub.site.com/api/index.php 404 (Not Found)" in the console log.

Comment: Are you sure you corrected the `url` arg? Can you edit your question to match your current code?

Comment: One problem... now accessing http://site.com/api/index.php from http://site.com/ (without sub) does not work...

Comment: this works. Thanks again Collin `if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])){

 $allow = array();
 $allow[] = "http://wwww.site.com";
 $allow[] = "http://site.com";
 $allow[] = "http://sub.site.com";
 
 if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'],$allow)){
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
 }

}`

Comment: To answer on why it works after fixing the `url` arg: "site.com/api/index.php" is not a well-formed URL; it makes sense to us humans, but software/frameworks/browsers/etc expect a well-formed one which includes the http:// :)