# Ajax request from Subdomain to main domain file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a website on which i am using sub domain to design the shopping area.

Example Website is `http://avc.com` and subdomain is `http://shop.avc.com/`. Subdomain points to `shop` folder onto the server.

Now, i have a login script that resides in main website folder not in subdomain.

Ps: At the time of checkout i am giving option to user login i.e. the URL for checkout will be `http://shop.avc.com/checkout` and the Login script is at `http://avc.com/login/verify.php`

Jquery used for AJAX call from subdomain is:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '../login/verify.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataString,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#loadingslogin").show();
        },

        complete: function(){
            $("#loadingslogin").hide();
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if(response != 5){
                $('#responsesign').html("<p class='alert alert-danger'>Oops! 
                Something wrong happened.").fadeIn().delay(15000).fadeOut();
            }
            else{
                $("input[type='text']").val('');
                $("input[type='password']").val('');
                $("#loadingslogin").hide();
                window.location.replace('checkout');
            }
        }            
    });
```

But the `verify.php` file is not getting executed. Any solutions please?

Comment: Is that just a typo in the path: `'..login/verify.php'`?

Comment: oops. it was a typo :)

Comment: Cross-domain issues, any messages in the console?

Comment: no messages... just in network tab the file just shows empty response

Comment: If there is an empty response, it seems it is getting executed. Check the server log, you should be able to narrow down the problem to the js or the php.

Comment: nop... the file is not available.. this was problem at my local also and i solved by pointing to right file... the URL is itself `http://shop.avc.com/login/verify.php` on AJAX req

Comment: You are mixing two different issues.

you can not link to your `/login/verify.php` using physical address in `javascript`.

in your hard drive, this relation between your files is correct and if you were supposed to link them using `php` you had to use this address, but you have to use `virtual addressing` for `javascripts`.

if you are in this address `http://shop.avc.com/checkout` and use `javascrip` to access this link: `../login/verify.php` then your `javascript` will look in this address: `http://shop.avc.com/login/` for your `verify.php` which does not exist.

Comment: Capture the error response. Add `error: function(xmlhr, errorStr) {
    // do something
  }`

Comment: @EhsanT . please suggest a solution also

Comment: OK, if you search in SO, you can find bunch of questions regarding the same issue. there are different solutions but I myself like [this hack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648899/a-question-about-cross-domain-subdomain-ajax-request/11147005#11147005) which is very easy to implement. you will get the idea. give it a try and if you had more questions, I'll be happy to help you. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990872/how-to-make-a-subdomain-ajax-call-with-jquery-without-iframes) you can find another answer, and the last comment in the answer is also pretty.

Comment: @EhsanT .. can u post this as an answer please

Comment: Hack `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648899/a-question-about-cross-domain-subdomain-ajax-request/11147005#11147005` worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As EhsanT has not posted his solution as an answer. So i am answering myself

[Fiddle Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648899/a-question-about-cross-domain-subdoma%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bin-ajax-request/11147005#11147005)

worked for me well

Comment: I'm glad to hear that this hack could help you solve your problem. have fun coding :)